# Caffeine tolerance

Tags: neuroscience, brain, receptor

I researched about caffeine tolerance and found out that regular consumption of coffe can build caffeine tolerance even if it's 1 cup per day, within few days or a week at most. Supposedly the body builds more adenosine receptors to cancel it's effect. My question is, is there any limit to it above which it can't neutralize the effect like a sweet spot say 3 cups which is neither unhealthy nor gets canceled by the body.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This question is kind of unanswerable as posed; how strong is the coffee? How large is your cup? These vary from country to country, and even just  how it's brewed matters. Caffeine isn't "neutralized", if it were, it would not work, and absolutely there's a limit to how much one can drink, which is why caffeinism is a thing. Finally, this reads to me as a request for personal medical advice, even though it's not phrased that way.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear, I am not asking a personal health advice or the likes of that. It is a general ques and you are free to assume anything not stated specifically as  it may seem fit to you in  a way that it helps with the ques

Comment: I think you want a frequency rather than a quantity, that is, how long do you need to wait between caffeinated beverages so that any tolerance from the previous one has decayed.

Comment: No, how much is the upper limit above which the body can't build tolerance.

Comment: "The upper limit above which the body can't build tolerance" depends on the frequency too, which is why frequency has been suggested instead of a quantity. You need to know the frequency and the caffeine concentration.

Comment: Caffeine has several effects on the human body, and as far as I recall, while some of those things can build up a tolerance, other's can't. This is true even within the brain itself.